# Phonegap: SocialSharing phonegap plugin not working with pre filled message in FBDialog

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

> Note : That bug is resolved now without single change in code. may be
>   by FB.

I am developing an app in Phonegap
platforms : iOS , Android

I am using this social sharing phonegap plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.

I have tried `window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook` and `window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebookWithPasteMessageHint` but i didn't got any success in sharing pre filled message through FBDialog

Any help would be heartily appreciated.

code :

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebookWithPasteMessageHint(
    "userMsz",
    null,
    null,
    'Message pasted to clip board ,press on the area to paste it in the feed',
    function(){}, 
    function(){}
);
```

Comment: "didn't got any success" which means (with more details)?..

Comment: Means I don't get FBDialog pre filled with message I had passed to plugin

Comment: This one is again getting reproduced in IOS 9

Answer (score 0):

**SOURCE :** [EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#4a-usage-on-ios-and-android)

Facebook with prefilled message

> On Android the user will see a Toast message with a message you control (default: "If you like you can paste a message from your clipboard").
>
> On iOS this function used to behave the same as shareViaFacebook, but since 4.3.18 a short message is shown prompting the user to paste a message (like Android). This message is not shown in case the Fb app is not installed since the internal iOS Fb share widget still supports prefilling the message.

```
<button
 onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebookWithPasteMessageHint('Message via Facebook', null /* img */, null /* url */, 'Paste it dude!', function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})">msg via Facebook (with errcallback)
</button>
```

Comment: Where that short message is shown because for me its not displaying any message